# Get XElement with XPathSelectElement

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, path, xelement

I have a XML file and loaded the specific tag `<Acct>` to an `XElement`. From this `XElement` in want to give a path to get the specific child `<BIC>` element. I don't wan't to use the `Descendates()` method. I tried using `XPathSelectElement` to get the job done but it always return null.
The XML Snippet i have looks something like this:

```
<Acct>
  <Id>
    <IBAN>TestIban</IBAN>
  </Id>
  <Ccy>EUR</Ccy>
  <Svcr>
    <FinInstnId>
      <BIC>TestBic</BIC>
      <ClrSysMmbId>
        <ClrSysId>
          <Cd>TestSysId</Cd>
        </ClrSysId>
        <MmbId>TestMemberId</MmbId>
      </ClrSysMmbId>
      <Nm>TestName</Nm>
      <PstlAdr>
        <AdrLine>TestAdrLine</AdrLine>
      </PstlAdr>
      <Othr>
        <Id>OtherId</Id>
        <Issr>Issr</Issr>
      </Othr>
    </FinInstnId>
  </Svcr>
</Acct>
```

Like i said the XElement i have is the tag  called acct. I tried now following to get the
`<BIC>` tag:

```
 var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement("Svrc/FinInstnId/BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement("/Svrc/FinInstnId/BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement("./Svrc/FinInstnId/BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement("Svrc//FinInstnId//BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement("//Svrc//FinInstnId//BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement(".//Svrc//FinInstnId//BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement("Acct/Svrc/FinInstnId/BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement("/Acct/Svrc/FinInstnId/BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement("./Acct/Svrc/FinInstnId/BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement("Acct//Svrc//FinInstnId//BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement("//Acct//Svrc//FinInstnId//BIC");
    var bic = acct.XPathSelectElement(".//Acct//Svrc//FinInstnId//BIC");
```

But all of these returning null. I found this article and they are doing in my point of view exactly the same:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204464/get-a-xelement-at-a-given-path

SO my question is how do i use the XPathSelectElement method from my XElement to get a child like the  tag as XElement?

Edit:

I inspected the XElement in Debug Mode with the Text Visualizer. The XML in the Element looks like the following (The values of the elements are different but this shouldn't change the problem):

```
 <Acct xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
  <Id>
    <IBAN>TestIban</IBAN>
  </Id>
  <Ccy>EUR</Ccy>
  <Svcr>
    <FinInstnId>
      <BIC>TestBic</BIC>
      <ClrSysMmbId>
        <ClrSysId>
          <Cd>Cd</Cd>
        </ClrSysId>
        <MmbId>TestMbmId</MmbId>
      </ClrSysMmbId>
      <Nm>SomeName</Nm>
      <PstlAdr>
        <AdrLine>Address</AdrLine>
      </PstlAdr>
      <Othr>
        <Id>Id</Id>
        <Issr>Issr</Issr>
      </Othr>
    </FinInstnId>
  </Svcr>
</Acct>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works fine

```
var xmlString = @"<root>
<Acct>
  <Id>
    <IBAN>TestIban</IBAN>
  </Id>
  <Ccy>EUR</Ccy>
  <Svcr>
    <FinInstnId>
      <BIC>TestBic</BIC>
      <ClrSysMmbId>
        <ClrSysId>
          <Cd>TestSysId</Cd>
        </ClrSysId>
        <MmbId>TestMemberId</MmbId>
      </ClrSysMmbId>
      <Nm>TestName</Nm>
      <PstlAdr>
        <AdrLine>TestAdrLine</AdrLine>
      </PstlAdr>
      <Othr>
        <Id>OtherId</Id>
        <Issr>Issr</Issr>
      </Othr>
    </FinInstnId>
  </Svcr>
</Acct>
</root>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
XElement acct = doc.XPathSelectElement("root/Acct");
XElement element = acct.XPathSelectElement("Svcr/FinInstnId/BIC");
Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
//print "TestBic"
```

are you sure `acct` contain right XElement?

update with namespace

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var reader = doc.CreateReader();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02");
XElement acct = doc.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Acct", nsmgr);
XElement element = acct.XPathSelectElement("*[local-name() = 'Svcr']/*[local-name() = 'FinInstnId']/*[local-name() = 'BIC']");
var anotherWay = acct.XPathSelectElement("ns:Svcr/ns:FinInstnId/ns:BIC", nsmgr);
```

with `local-name()` you can ignore namespace

Comment: @Max upd answer

Comment: thanks, your updated solution works fine!